# Simple ANTLR grammar not disambiguating identifiers and literals

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to match this syntax:

```
P = 100
require P
credit account:subaccount P
```

The first is an assignment. The second is a "check" that P is truthy. The third is an instruction to move 100 to account:subaccount. The problem is that the grammar I've written thinks the third line is just an assignment with a missing equal sign. I can't see why.

```
program: (stmt NEWLINE)+;

stmt: require | entry;

require: 'require' filtrex;
entry: (CREDIT | DEBIT) JOURNAL filtrex (IF filtrex)? (LPARENHASH EXTID RPAREN)?;
assign: ID EQ filtrex;

filtrex: math;

math
   :  math (TIMES | DIV)  math
   |  math (PLUS | MINUS) math
   |  LPAREN math RPAREN
   |  (PLUS | MINUS)* atom
   ;

atom: NUMBER
   | ID
   ;

NUMBER
   : ('0' .. '9') + ('.' ('0' .. '9') +)?
   ;

fragment SIGN
   : ('+' | '-')
   ;

ID: [a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*;
EQ: '=';
JOURNAL: [a-zA-Z:]+;
EXTID: [a-zA-Z0-9-]+;
COLON: ':';
CREDIT: 'credit';
DEBIT: 'debit';
IF: 'if';
NEWLINE : [\r\n];
NUM     : [0-9.]+;
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
LPARENHASH: '(#';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
TIMES: '*';
DIV: '/' ;
POINT: '.';
WS: [ \r\n\t] + -> skip;
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to the suggestions below I have something that seems to work properly. Now to the implementation of the logic...

```
grammar Txl;

// High level language
program: stmt (NEWLINE stmt)* NEWLINE? EOF;

stmt: require | entry | assignment;

require: 'require' expr;
entry: (CREDIT | DEBIT) journal expr (IF expr)? (LPAREN 'id:' EXTID RPAREN)?;
assignment: IDENT ASSIGN expr;

journal: IDENT COLON IDENT;

expr: expr MULT expr
    | expr DIV expr
    | expr PLUS expr
    | expr MINUS expr
    | expr MOD expr
    | expr POW expr
    | MINUS expr
    | expr AND expr
    | expr OR expr
    | NOT expr
    | expr EQ expr
    | expr NEQ expr
    | expr LTE expr
    | expr LT expr
    | expr GTE expr
    | expr GT expr
    | expr QUESTION expr COLON expr
    | LPAREN expr RPAREN
    | NUMBER
    | IDENT LPAREN args RPAREN
    | IDENT
    ;

fnArg: expr | journal;

args: fnArg
    | fnArg COMMA fnArg
    |
    ;

// Reserved words
CREDIT: 'credit';
DEBIT: 'debit';
IF: 'if';
REQUIRE: 'require';

// Operators
MULT: '*';
DIV: '/';
MINUS: '-';
PLUS: '+';
POW: '^';
MOD: '%';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
LBRACE: '[';
RBRACE: ']';
COMMA: ',';
EQ: '==';
NEQ: '!=';
GTE: '>=';
LTE: '<=';
GT: '>';
LT: '<';
ASSIGN: '=';
QUESTION: '?';
COLON: ':';
AND: 'and';
OR: 'or';
NOT: 'not';
HASH: '#';
NEWLINE : [\r\n];
WS: [ \t] + -> skip;

// Entities
NUMBER: ('0' .. '9') + ('.' ('0' .. '9') +)?;
IDENT: [a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*;
EXTID: [a-zA-Z0-9-]+;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the input `credit` is not being matched by your `CREDIT` rule, but by the `ID` rule. The lexer always tries to match as many characters as possible. So, the input `credit` can be matched by: `ID`, `JOURNAL`, `EXTID` and `CREDIT`. Whenever it happens that multiple rules can match the same characters, the one defined first "wins" (`ID` in this case). The lexer does not "listen" to what the parser is trying to match, it operates independently from the parser.

Note that the `EXTID` also causes the input `-` to be matched by it, causing the `MINUS` rule to never be matched.

The solution: place your keywords *before* the `ID` rule inside the grammar:

```
CREDIT     : 'credit';
DEBIT      : 'debit';
REQUIRE    : 'require';
ID         : [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9a-zA-Z]*;
```

And, if possible, I'd also remove the `JOURNAL` and `EXTID` lexer rules and try to "promote" them to parser rules:

```
journal
 : ID COLON ID
 ;

extid
 : ID (MINUS ID)*
 ;
```

`NUMBER` and `NUM` can also match the same, while `NUM` also matches input like `1........2.......22222...`. I'd remove the `NUM` rule and only keep `NUMBER`.

Remove the `\r\n` part from `WS: [ \r\n\t] + -> skip;` since these are already matched by your `NEWLINE` rule.

By doing `(stmt NEWLINE)+`, every `stmt` must end with a new line (also the last one). This could be a better solution: `stmt (NEWLINE stmt)* NEWLINE?`.

The grammar could look like this:

```
program
 : stmt (NEWLINE stmt)* NEWLINE? EOF
 ;

stmt
 : require
 | entry
 | assign
 ;

require
 : REQUIRE filtrex
 ;

entry
 : (CREDIT | DEBIT) journal filtrex (IF filtrex)? (LPARENHASH extid RPAREN)?
 ;

assign
 : ID EQ filtrex
 ;

journal
 : ID COLON ID
 ;

extid
 : ID (MINUS ID)*
 ;

filtrex
 : math
 ;

math
 : math (TIMES | DIV)  math
 | math (PLUS | MINUS) math
 | LPAREN math RPAREN
 | (PLUS | MINUS)* atom
 ;

atom
 : NUMBER
 | ID
 ;

NUMBER     : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;
CREDIT     : 'credit';
DEBIT      : 'debit';
REQUIRE    : 'require';
IF         : 'if';
ID         : [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9a-zA-Z]*;
EQ         : '=';
COLON      : ':';
NEWLINE    : [\r\n];
LPAREN     : '(';
RPAREN     : ')';
LPARENHASH : '(#';
PLUS       : '+';
MINUS      : '-';
TIMES      : '*';
DIV        : '/' ;
POINT      : '.';
WS         : [ \t] + -> skip;
```

which will parse your example input like this:

[image]

Comment: `IF` also needs to be above `ID`

Comment: Good catch @Clashsoft, missed that one.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is amazingly helpful. I'm trying to port this: https://github.com/gas-buddy/async-rule-evaluator/blob/master/src/language.js and then add this "top level" grammar to it so this really clears up a bunch of confusion.